# 2012 Toyota Camry - Hesitation

Tags: toyota, camry, hesitation

My 2012 Camry seems to be hesitating upon acceleration, the dealer has test-driven it and reported they didn't see a problem.

What could be causing this?

Comment: So, they drive it with no hesitation ... What have you checked so far?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles on the Camry? What maintenance has been done to the vehicle? Did this just start happening? Does it do it all the time, or is it sporadic?